# Creating copy string in Python via scrolling

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to scroll through one string and add each character to another string to create a new string.

I have the following function

```
def rocConvert(self, s):
    newString = ""
    for c in s:
        if c.isupper():
            newString += c
        elif c.islower():
            newString += c
        else:
            newString += c

    return newString
```

For some reason this is only returning the first char of s.  Note, I realize my method is kind of weird for just copying: my end function willl actually be changing the value if it's a lower or upper case character.

Why is this only returning the first character of s?

Comment: I am receiving the entire input string as a return using your unaltered code in Python 2.7.4 console

Comment: Works fine for me too. python 2.7.5

Comment: Indentation issues in the script maybe?

Comment: It works for me: http://ideone.com/yHXaoP

Comment: Try running your code using `-tt`, i.e. `python -tt your_program_name.py`.  Possibly there's a mixed tabs-and-spaces issue, so your `return` is actually indented inside the `for` loop, even though it may not look like it.

Comment: Set your text editor to insert 4 spaces in place of tabs. There's even a PEP backing that up somewhere...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should probably be adding your new string to a list and then using `''.join(your_list)`.  `+=` operator on strings creates a new string each time.

Answer (score 4):

Indentation bug. Your `return` has two tabs in front of it in what you've posted. DSM's `-tt` suggestion is good.